# Installing EGit on eclipse causes problems

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, egit

I've tried installing the EGit plugin on Eclipse with this link: http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates

I chose both, the `Eclipse Git Team Provider` and `JGit` and hit on next. Then, the window says `The operation cannot be completed. See the details.`.

This is the window:

[image]

The error lines say:

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.

  Software being installed: Eclipse Git Team Provider 3.0.3.201309161630-r
 (org.eclipse.egit.feature.group 3.0.3.201309161630-r)

  Software currently installed: Eclipse SDK 3.7.2.M20120208-0800 (org.eclipse.sdk.ide 3.7.2.M20120208-0800)

  Only one of the following can be installed at once:
    Team Support Core 3.7.0.v20130514-1224 (org.eclipse.team.core 3.7.0.v20130514-1224)
    Team Support Core 3.5.0.I20090527-0620 (org.eclipse.team.core 3.5.0.I20090527-0620)
    Team Support Core 3.5.1.r35x_20100113-0800 (org.eclipse.team.core 3.5.1.r35x_20100113-0800)
    Team Support Core 3.6.0.I20110525-0800 (org.eclipse.team.core 3.6.0.I20110525-0800)


  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse Git Team Provider 3.0.3.201309161630-r (org.eclipse.egit.feature.group 3.0.3.201309161630-r)
    To: org.eclipse.egit.ui [3.0.3.201309161630-r]


  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Git Team Provider UI 3.0.3.201309161630-r (org.eclipse.egit.ui 3.0.3.201309161630-r)
    To: bundle org.eclipse.team.core [3.6.100,4.0.0)


  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse Platform 3.7.2.v20120207-1839-9gF7UHPDFxGjd-PqDr2jX_4yKaumkoHTz04_q-q (org.eclipse.platform.feature.group 3.7.2.v20120207-1839-9gF7UHPDFxGjd-PqDr2jX_4yKaumkoHTz04_q-q)
    To: org.eclipse.team.core [3.6.0.I20110525-0800]


  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse Project SDK 3.7.2.r37x_v20111213-7Q7xALDPb32vCjY6UACVPdFTz-icPtJkUadz0lMmk4z-8 (org.eclipse.sdk.feature.group 3.7.2.r37x_v20111213-7Q7xALDPb32vCjY6UACVPdFTz-icPtJkUadz0lMmk4z-8)
    To: org.eclipse.platform.feature.group [3.7.2.v20120207-1839-9gF7UHPDFxGjd-PqDr2jX_4yKaumkoHTz04_q-q]


  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse SDK 3.7.2.M20120208-0800 (org.eclipse.sdk.ide 3.7.2.M20120208-0800)
    To: org.eclipse.sdk.feature.group [3.7.2.r37x_v20111213-7Q7xALDPb32vCjY6UACVPdFTz-icPtJkUadz0lMmk4z-8]
```

I really don't know what is going on, but I want to get this to work so badly. Thanks in advance for everyone's support!

Comment: have u update eclipse

Comment: @BalajiD one second, I'll check

Comment: @BalajiD there was an update, but it didn't fix the error :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the error message it looks like you are using Eclipse 3.7 (which is about 2 years old at the time of writing this answer).

EGit 3.0 requires at least Eclipse 3.8.2 or Eclipse 4.2.2, see  [What versions of Eclipse does EGit target?](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/FAQ#What_versions_of_Eclipse_does_EGit_target.3F)  in the FAQ.

So the solution is to upgrade to a recent version of Eclipse, see [Eclipse downloads](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/).

Comment: Oh wow, I thought 3.8.2 was the newest version because it didn't tell me that there weren't any later updates. Thank you very much, it works now!

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you need to stick to Eclipse **3.7.2** for some reason, you can use EGit version **1.3**. This is the best update site to use in that case: [eclipse indigo update site](http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo/). If you filter by "git" you will get the correct plugins to install.

[image: update dialog filter by 'git']